# Can you populate a List<Integer> within a user defined constructor?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I'm new to Java and hoping for some advice on instantiating `List<Integer>` arrays within a user defined constructor.

for example:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Sample {

    // variables
    private List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<>(); 
    
    // constructor
    // list of values something like (1,2,3,4,5)
    public Sample(List<Integer> listOfValues)
    {

        {
            myListArrays.addAll(Arrays.asList( listOfValues ));
        }   
    }
        
}
```

So my constructor call would be:

```
Sample s = new Sample((1,2,3,4,5));
```

Is it possible to do something like the above or is there an alternative approach to this type of assignment?

Comment: @Rono the OP still need to change `myListArrays.addAll(listOfValues);` in the constructor with your solution

Answer (score 5):

If you want to make a call like that, then you need to use [varargs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html).

```java
public Sample(Integer... listOfValues)
{
    myListArrays.addAll(Arrays.asList(listOfValues));
}
```

```java
Sample s = new Sample(1,2,3,4,5);
```

See also: [Varargs in Java | Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/java-varargs)

Comment: @StudentAccount4 Why would we need a length check for that? `new Sample()` will call the contructor with an `Integer[0]` as the `listOfValues`, making `Arrays.asList()` return an empty list, making `addAdd()` not add anything to `myListArrays`, and we get exactly what we wanted, without any unnecessary extra code.

Comment: @StudentAccount4 That comment is not making any sense. We're not creating the `myListArrays` list here, just adding to it, and we certainly shouldn't replace `myListArrays` with a `Collections.emptyList()`, because we don't know if values might be added later, and the list returned by `emptyList()` is immutable, so that would cause havoc.

Comment: @StudentAccount4 The list created by `Arrays.asList()` is so short-lived, it doesn't matter if it creates a new object. If you wanted to "optimize" it, you would skip the entire `addAll()` call with an `if` statement, and wouldn't use `Collections.emptyList()` anyway, so I don't know why that one was even mentioned as relevant to this code. Unless you're creating a humongous number of `Sample` instances, such micro-optimizations are a waste. Even if you do, skipping that small one is so minuscule compared to everything else, that you probably would never be able to tell the difference.

Comment: @StudentAccount4 Even with the length check, the call still created an `Integer[0]` for the parameter, so if you truly wanted to optimize the call, you would create a no-arg overloaded constructor. In short, adding a length check to the constructor shown here is just ... *meaningless!!*

Comment: @StudentAccount4 this code is for specifically creating an `ArrayList`. When you don’t need this specific result type, you don’t need to call `addAll` at all, but can just use `myListArrays = listOfValues.length==0? Collections.emptyList(): listOfValues.length==1? Collections.singletonList(listOfValues[0]): Arrays.asList(listOfValues);` or use Java 9+ and avoid `null` elements, as then, you can just use `myListArrays = List.of(…)`, avoid varargs overhead (for length<=10), and get optimized implementations at the JRE’s discretion (currently for zero, one, or two elements).

Answer (score 0):

## Declare without instantiating

The task is to instantiate it in the constructor, therefore you do not need to instantiate it at declaration:

```
private List<Integer> myList;
```

## You can pass a parameter to the constructor

```
public Sample(Integer[] values) {
    myList = Arrays.asList(values)
}
```

## Call it

```
Integer[] elements = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
Sample mySample = new Sample(elements);
```